# Data on morocco exchange reserves

Tags: options, time-series, data, fx, exchange

i'm trying to do some tests on exchange market pressure of morocco 
Where can i find data on morocco exchange reserves
 thanks

Answer (score 2):

Morocco central bank should have an estimation of their reserves. http://www.bkam.ma/Publications-statistiques-et-recherche/Documents-d-information-et-de-statistiques/Statistiques-monetaires